# RMI server picking up an old ip address

Tags: java, spring, rmi

I am seeing a strange problem:

I have a linux machine, installed JDK1.6 on that machine, and some business went on, and some days later had to change the IP address of the machine. and now after some months... i am trying to get some spring application to work... and it seems the RMI Server is starting at my old ip address...

```
    21:12:45,412 DEBUG [org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter] RMI registry access threw exception
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 192.168.13.55; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:614)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.list(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter.testRegistry(RmiServiceExporter.java:411)
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter.getRegistry(RmiServiceExporter.java:391)
```

can somone explain the process or shed some light on what is going on here, or might be going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, thanks for the response... i really appreciate that...but i was probably too drunk to notice the entries in my /etc/hosts file were binding my hostname to the old IP address...so as soon as i removed that...things worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your spring config to ensure you don't have an old reference somewhere?